# ASCollectionView and ASCellNode in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, asyncdisplaykit

I am trying to use AsyncDisplayKit to load images into my app. I am creating my collection view as an ASCollectionView, like so, in the viewDidLoad:

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 90, height: 90)
    let collection = ASCollectionView(frame: view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

    collection.asyncDataSource = self
    collection.asyncDelegate = self
    collection.registerClass(cell1.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(collection.layer)
```

Here is my nodeForItemAtIndexPath:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: ASCollectionView, nodeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: 
NSIndexPath) -> ASCellNode {

   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell1", 
   forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell1

    return cell
}
```

nodeForItemAtindexPath is the AsyncDisplayKit version of cellForItemAtIndexPath. It must be used with the ASCollectionView.

The problem is that the method "collecitonView.dequeueRreusableCellWithReuseIdentifier" returns a UICollecitonViewCell. My cell is not that, it is an ASCellNode. So I get an error: "cast from UICollectionViewCell to unrelated type ASNodeCell always fails".

I also get an error at this line:

```
  collection.registerClass(cell1.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell1")
```

The error says "attempt to register a cell class which is not a subclass of UICollectionViewCell."

Is there some other way to work around this? I have searched just about everywhere, but there are very few resources available in Swift (or obj c for that matter) concerning asyncdisplaykit, and I can't find a single example project that uses ASCollectionView. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AsyncDisplayKit it is not necessary to register cell classes with your `ASCollectionNode/View`

In your `nodeForItemAtIndexPath` you will need to instantiate a new cell node every time rather than dequeueing a cell.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: ASCollectionView, nodeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ASCellNode {

    let node = ASCellNode()

    return node
}
```

The [AsyncDisplayKit github](https://github.com/facebook/AsyncDisplayKit) project has more examples of how to implement this